# Como fazer para elemento aparecer apenas para usuários do Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho um site que não está meio desalinhado no **Mozilla Firefox**, testei em alguns navegadores, inclusive o **Internet Explorer**, que por sinal exibiu a página perfeitamente.

Somente o **Mozilla Firefox** está com esse problema. No momento estou meio sem tempo pra tentar resolver isto, então quero que quando a pessoa acessar o site, seja exibido um aviso para ela, indicando a utilização de outro navegador.

Exemplo de código:

```
<div id="mozilla"> Percebemos que você está utilizando o navegador Mozilla.
     Para uma melhor interação com nosso site, indicamos que utilize
    outro navegador, como Google Chrome, Internet Explorer, etc.
<span id="x">Fechar</span> </div>
```

> É possível fazer com que este aviso acima apareça somente caso a pessoa acesse a página utilizando o navegador **Mozilla Firefox**?

Outra coisinha, como dar `style="display:none"` à `<div>`, caso a pessoa clique em fechar?

Comment: Podes colocar aqui um exemplo do que não funciona? pode ser útil para outros e podemos ajudar a resolver...

Comment: Eu não fiz, rsrs, é só uma dúvida que quero implimentar em meu site :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var isFirefox = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') != -1;
```

Essa linha procura a palavra `firefox` na assinatura digital do browser, no userAgent string.

Se `isFirefox` for `true` é um browser Firefox.

Comment: Que legal !!!! :D :D :D

Comment: Sergio, desculpa, é que sou um pouco leigo, dá pra me mostrar com o exemplo que citei ? :P

Comment: @AlexandreLopes https://jsfiddle.net/z91rh3L3/

Comment: Genial !!! Meu parabéns Sergio, você tem um conhecimento itanto. Muito obrigado por ajudar os novatos como esse cara aqui :P